# Problem with Dictionary<string, string>

Tags: c#, exception, dictionary

Can anyone help me?

I had a simple code:

```
private void ObterRelatorios(string id) { 
    var relatorios = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    var xml = new XmlDocument();

    xml.Load("my_path");

    foreach (XmlNode node in relatoriosStaticos.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
        relatorios.Add(node.Attributes["Titulo"].InnerText, string.Concat(node.Attributes["Url"].InnerText, id));
}
```

My xml is quite simple with 5 nodes and always is the same.

This is wierd because sometimes works, sometimes not.

This is what I get when throw an exception

**Error Details:**

```
Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
```

**Full Stack:**

```
[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key]
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error says "[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key]"

The value for:

`node.Attributes["Titulo"].InnerText`

apparently is null in some cases, and this is not allowed. The key for a dictionary entry cannot be null.

Comment: Unfortunaly this node always have a value inside...
This is a xml that never change and works most of the time!

Comment: Why don't you use the debugger to look at the data when it fails? Maybe there is a problem loading the XML file sometimes. It's not very likely that the node has a value, and you are getting this error. That would indicate a bug in a .NET framework object that's used by millions of people. It's much more likely that there's something going wrong between your XML file, and the XML node you are creating from it.

Comment: Because it's in a big system on production and on my machine I can't simulate the error.

Comment: Then add some error trapping and send yourself an email with the same info, or log it to a file.

Comment: Thanks Jamietre for your time :)

I will try trap this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a "Titulo" Node is in some cases empty. You have to check it before you want to add it to your Dictionary, because the Key-Property can`t have empty Value.

Here an example to prevent it.

```
foreach (XmlNode node in relatoriosStaticos.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
{
    if (node.Attributes["Titulo"].InnerText == string.Empty)
    {
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        relatorios.Add(node.Attributes["Titulo"].InnerText,
            string.Concat(node.Attributes["Url"].InnerText, id));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why this is happen in some cases because the xml never changes, but anyway i will change to this prevent code!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you always have value in your `node.Attributes["Titulo"].InnerText` attribute.  If not you will have ArgumentNullException.  You can't have null value for key in Dictionary.

Comment: Unfortunaly I am sure of that !

Comment: How do you populate relatoriosStaticos object?

Answer (score 0):

Just to say, I had this same error, `Value cannot be null`, when using `ToDictionary()` and two of the Key values were the same.

I didn't realise this, and found the error message a little misleading, as none of my values were null.

My solution (applying it to your problem) would be to take your original code:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in relatoriosStaticos.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
        relatorios.Add(node.Attributes["Titulo"].InnerText, string.Concat(node.Attributes["Url"].InnerText, id));
```

And split it into two parts.

First, populate a `List<>` variable with a list of Keys & Values, which you plan to put into a `Dictionary`.

```
public class KeysAndValues
{
    public string Key;
    public string Value;

    public override string ToString()
    {
       return string.Format("{0}: {1}", Key, Value);
    }
}

List<KeysAndValues> dict = new List<KeysAndValues>();
foreach (XmlNode node in relatoriosStaticos.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
{
    dict.Add(new KeysAndValues() 
    {
        Key = node.Attributes["Titulo"].InnerText,
        Value = string.Concat(node.Attributes["Url"].InnerText, id)
    });
}
```

Next, get your code to check for NULL values, and duplicated Key values.

If all's well, then we can convert the List<> into a Dictionary.

```
foreach (KeysAndValues kv in dict)
{
    relatorios.Add(kv.Key, kv.Value);
}
```

It's a little more work, but this is a neat way to check for `Dictionary` problems, rather than waiting for an Exception to occur, if there's a problem with your data.